# ChartJs 2 How to remove numbers from the doughnut chart on loading

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

So, I have this doughnut chart that on loading displays the data numbers on the chart segments. It clutters the chart and I cannot find a way to get it out. I tried:

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
```

But, this removes the legend, not the labels on the chart.[image]

So, 1) how do I clean out the chart by removing these datalabels? 2) As seen in this picture, the chart is being cropped on the left and the right.  I did check the width and height of the canvas, and it looks like it has more space to grow into. So, why is the chart being cropped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chart.js does not draw any data labels itself by default. You most probably have activated (imported) a plugin such as [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/blob/master/README.md) that draws these labels.

> To [disable a global plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#disable-plugins) for a specific chart instance, the `plugin` options must be set to `false`.

In the case of `chartjs-plugin-datalabels`, this would be done as follows:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      display: false
    }
  },
}
```

To avoid the cropped data labels, you can define some extra space to the left and the right of the chart through the option [`layout.padding`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html#padding) as shown below:

```
options: {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 50,
      right: 50
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Also, do you know how to use hoverBackgroundColor so it gives it a popup look when hovering on a pie/doughnut segment of the chart?

Comment: @EarlyCoder: `hoverBackgroundColor` needs to be defined on the `dataset`. It's an array that typically contain the same colors as `backgroundColor` but with different opacity each. For defining the opacity, you can use the CSS `rgba()` function.

Comment: That is great. But, is there a way to increase the size of the pie segment when the user hovers on it?

Comment: @EarlyCoder: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61555987/2358409