# How do I remove the ticks or inner circles of my polar area chart Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, chart.js

I have written the code for my chart in Jquery and I am using the chart to display data on my Django Web Page, I want to remove the inner circles which I think are called ticks along with the small numbers that are displayed with them. I have tried to use the

ticks:{
display: false,
}

and

scale:{
display: false,
}

but have had no luck with either I am not sure how to do it.

Code for Chart:

```
            new Chart("chart_{{ i.pk }}_{{ t.pk }}", {
              type: "polarArea",
              data: {
                labels: labels_{{ t.pk }},
                datasets: [{
                  fill: true,
                  pointRadius: 1,
{#                  borderColor: backgroundColors_{{ t.pk }} ,#}
                  backgroundColor: backgroundColors_{{ t.pk }} ,
                  data: totals_{{ i.pk }}_{{ t.pk }}_arr,
                }]
              },
              options: {
                responsive: false,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                    scale: {
                        ticks: {
                            display: false,
                        },
                        gridLines: {
                                display: false,
                                lineWidth: 7,
                                tickMarkLength: 30// Adjusts the height for the tick marks area
                        },
                        
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: 'Chart.js Polar Area Chart'
                    }
                }
              }
            });

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63313163/2358409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v3 the radialLinear scale is not configured in the `scale` object anymore but also in the `scales` namespace with namespace `r` for radial. Also it shouldn't be configured in the plugins section but in the root of the the options object.
And as last the `gridLines` has been renamed to `grid`.

For all changes between V2 and V3 please read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Live example:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'polarArea',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      r: {
        ticks: {
          display: false // Remove vertical numbers
        },
        grid: {
          display: false // Removes the circulair lines
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```