# react-chartjs2: How to hide the labels (not legend that appears on top) that appears OVER the graph line (not the x / y axis) in a Line Graph?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, linegraph, react-chartjs-2

How I want the graph to look:

[image: how I want the graph to look]

How it currently looks:

[image: how it currently looks]

Code for the component:

```
function LineGraph() {

  ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Filler,
    Legend
  );

  const data = {
    labels: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [50, 35, 45, 42, 70, 65, 100], // Add your data here
        pointRadius: 0,
        fill: 'origin', // This fills the area under the line
        backgroundColor: (context: any) => {
          const ctx = context.chart.ctx;
          const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
          gradient.addColorStop(0, "#EEECFE");
          gradient.addColorStop(1, "#EEECFE80");
          return gradient;
        }, // Set the color you want
        borderColor: '#A496FF', // Set the color of the line
        tension: 0.5,
      },
    ],
  };

  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false // This hides the legend

      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: { // Hides the x-axis labels
        display: false,
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      },
      y: { // Hides the y-axis labels
        display: false,
        min: 0,
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      },
    },
  };


  return (
    <div className="absolute bottom-0 px-[1.88rem] w-full h-[8.75rem]">
      <Line data={data} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Goal: To hide/remove the labels that are visible over the line graph i.e. those small data labels that we're seeing (35, 45, 42, etc).

I've tried doing `pointRadius: 0` and `x: { ticks: { display: false } }` under `options` but it hasn't helped. I'm pretty sure that the latter has nothing to do with the labels on the line graph.

1. What mistake am I making here?
2. How to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63313163/2358409

Answer (score 0):

The stack-overflow post pointed out by @uminder solved my problem. Check out his link, it's more informative.

As answered by @uminder, Chart.js does not draw any labels by default. I had activated a global plugin called `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` for another doughnut chart of mine which needed labels.

Here I needed to make the following changes to disable the plugin from working in this graph:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
  // adding this to hide the datalabels.
  datalabels: {
      display: false
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: If the answer to another question also answers yours, then you should accept the proposed duplicate in the blue box you are presented with, now that that has been formally suggested.

Comment: @AdrianMole the website says that I can't accept my own answer in 15 hours. I'll try to accept it after 24 hours.